# xslt sort by two columns, where one is only partial

Tags: xslt, sorting

I have many nodes I wish to sort.
 - They all have a create date.
 - Some have an edit date to.

(update)
Since no ansers I will add an example of en xml document to search

```
<page>
 <createdate>2010-01-05</createdate>
 <editdate>2010-01-07</editdate>
</page>
<page>
 <createdate>2010-01-06</createdate>
 <editdate></editdate>  (do not know is this row is there at all)
</page>
<page>
 <createdate>2010-01-07</createdate>
 <editdate>2010-01-10</editdate>
</page>
```

I would like a sort that order by "createdate and use "editdate" if it exist.

Can this be done in XSLT 1.0?

BR. Anders

UPDATE: SOLVED by solution given below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a concatenation of editdate and createdate as the selection for the xsl:sort?
like

```
 <xsl:for-each select="page">
   <xsl:sort select="concat(editdate, createdate)"/>
   <!-- do stuff -->
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thant was a great idea! Never thought of it. Will try it out and get back with result. I guess it should work

Comment: Otherwise I came across this links that might be the base for another solution with a temp result based on both dates that then is sorted further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017423/xslt-1-0-sorting-between-multiple-documents